# opengl and SDL copmpilation on ubuntu

Tags: c++, opengl, g++, glu

I've already installed this :
(and i think all the library needed)

```
libglu1-mesa-dev
libglu1-mesa
```

but when i tried to compile a simple program i've got :

```
g++  -o test 50_SDL_and_opengl_2.cpp `sdl2-config --libs --cflags`  -lGL -lGLU
```

this :

```
50_SDL_and_opengl_2.cpp:7:20: fatal error: GL\GLU.h: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
#include <GL\GLU.h>
```

Comment: Check out this post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=395396&p=2365634#post2365634

Comment: Yes, I know the French cultivate their language, and I think this is quite good practice. But it really narrows down the people who can help you if error messages are localized. Please when asking for help with build errors clear your locale, i.e. `export LANG="C"`, `export LC_ALL="C"` and unset all of the other `LC_…` environment variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be "GL/glu.h" and not "GL\GLU.h"
(notice the lowercase filename and the slash instead of backslash)